# Apache access logs request

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I'm seeing some requests for "GET / HTTP/1.1" and they're showing a 200 result-- is this the root of the vhost, or the web root??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET /` is a request for the vHost (website) root, for example https://serverfault.com/
A 200 response indicates success.

Comment: so if the vhost root is /var/webstuff/mydomain/index.php that request gets index.php, correct? Not the webroot of the apache server (eg. /var/webstuff)

Thanks!

Comment: Correct. The only way to get /var/webstuff is if that's a document root for a different domain.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I thought that was the case but needed to verify.